# Превратить числа в текст на английском языке

Tags: c++

Есть задача в Практикуме:

В английском языке числительные строятся примерно как в русском — числа до двадцати имеют самостоятельные имена: 0 — zero, 1 — one, 2 — two, 3 — three, 4 — four, 5 — five, 6 — six, 7 — seven, 8 — eight, 9 — nine, 10 — ten, 11 — eleven, 12 — twelve, 13 — thirteen, 14 — fourteen, 15 — fifteen, 16 — sixteen, 17 — seventeen, 18 — eighteen, 19 — nineteen.
В числах от 20 до 99 десятки и единицы записываются через дефис. Например: 24 — twenty-four, 48 — forty-eight. Десятки называются так: 20 — twenty, 30 — thirty, 40 — fourty, 50 — fifty, 60 — sixty, 70 — seventy, 80 — eighty, 90 — ninety.
Напишите программу для превращения чисел в текст на английском языке. Пока что достаточно ограничиться двузначными числами.
Все английские слова даны в заготовке кода.

С первым пунктом справился, а вот со вторым и третьим уже возникли проблемы.

Моя попытка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> tens_names = {"twenty"s, "thirty"s, "fourty"s, "fifty"s,
                                 "sixty"s, "seventy"s, "eighty"s, "ninety"s};

    vector<string> num_names = { "zero"s, "one"s, "two"s, "three"s, "four"s, "five"s,
                                 "six"s, "seven"s, "eight"s, "nine"s, "ten"s, "eleven"s,
                                 "twelve"s, "thirteen"s, "fourteen"s, "fifteen"s,
                                 "sixteen"s, "seventeen"s, "eighteen"s, "nineteen"s};
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    int units = number % 10;
    int tens = number / 10;
    cout << units << " " << tens << endl;
    // Если число меньше 20, то выведите элемент из num_names.
    if (number < 20)
    cout << num_names[number] << endl;
    // Иначе, если единицы равны нулю, то выведите элемент tenth_names.
    else if (units == 0)
    cout << tens_names[units] << endl;
    // Иначе выведите через дефис значения из tenth_names и num_names.
    system("pause");
}
```

Постоянно выводит только twenty (при вводе числа >= 20, числа от нуля до 19 обрабатываются корректно).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит отметить, что Вы выводите что-то для чисел >= 20 в том случае, если `units` — последняя цифра числа — равна 0. Поскольку Вы используете только эту переменную для того, чтоб доставать значения из массива `tens_names`, то и доставаться будет тоже только первый элемент, т.е. `twenty`.

Замените `cout << tens_names[units] << endl;` на `cout << tens_names[tens - 2] << endl;`, и тогда программа будет нормально выводить числа для кратных 10.

<sub>С учётом задания я бы вообще убрал второй `if` и выводил десятки в любом случае, вот для дефисов и дополнительных слов, пожалуй, стоит оставить условный оператор.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Alexey не забудьте закрыть вопрос и отметить ответ как верный, если проблема решена